# Google Sign in button not working on server

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I am getting a weird issue. Google sing in button is working fine on my local system (using url: localhost) but it is not working on the server.
It keep giving me error 400 Error: invalid_request
[image: see error page here]

I have added my server url on google console and even verified my URL

I am using example code from [here](http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

See my demo [here](http://ec2-54-175-82-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com/user/login)

Answer (score 0):

> For use with requests from a web server. This is the path in your
>   application that users are redirected to after they have authenticated
>   with Google. The path will be appended with the authorization code for
>   access. Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative
>   paths. Cannot be a public IP address.

Your redirect URI should probably look more like this.

```
http://ec2-54-175-82-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com/user/auth
```

When your code runs it has built the following request (Put this in any web browser.)

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Fec2-54-175-82-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com%3Fid%3Dauth315255&response_type=permission%20id_token&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&client_id=651551554260-60j7jq0i2gjsfm1mm0rh74ie4m80md5i.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-54-175-82-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2

If you look at the redirect URI.

```
storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Fec2-54-175-82-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com%3Fid%3Dauth315255
```

Its not correct.   It should be the page on your website that is designed to handle the authentication.

Comment: I have added this path is Google console, but its still not working

Comment: see my console settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmGq4.png
and domain verification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TqwZ.png

Comment: Yes but look at the error message.   You aren't sending the request from there.  The Redirect URI must exactly match where you are sending it from.

Comment: I am not sending it manually. This is all done by platform.js from google api.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, try setting the redirect_uri to "postmessage". It should do the magic.